# How to extract URL and store it to MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a textarea in which user enter url and link is extracted successfully and appended to a div. How can I store that extracted data into database as the extracted data is in a div not in any input?

```
<textarea id="get_url" placeholder="Enter Your URL here" class="get_url_input" spellcheck="false" ></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Share">
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Extracted data is shown in result div, do I need to store the response into any hidden input and check if it is empty while clicking on share button?

Comment: Pull the value with javascript then send it to the DB via ajax..or make a hidden input. Do you have a form already?

Comment: @chris85 Yes i have a form already!

Comment: Just make a hidden input then and populate it.

Comment: @chris85 Ok i will try it

Comment: Instead of using a `<textarea>` to simply *input* a URL, just use a standard text input `<input type="text" id="get_url" placeholder="Enter Your URL here" class="get_url_input">` and then drop the contents of the URL into a `<textarea id="url_data" name="data_from_url"></textarea>` via javascript. You can then pass that data to your database on a form submission.

Comment: Could you reword your first sentence? I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. You want to grab the user's input from the textarea, which will be a url, then you want to store that into a database, but I'm not sure what you meant after that part. This part :"as the extracted data is in a div not in any input." confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this but I would recommend using:

> Ajax and JQuery

In your ***JavaScript*** file add:

```
var data = $('#div id').text(); 
    $.ajax ({
           url: "www.websitename.com/addurl.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { urltoadd: data},
    success: function (response){
       If (response = 'successful'){
return true;
}else {
return false;
}
    }
    });
```

Now in your ***addurl.php*** file:

```
<?php 
$urltoadd = $_POST ['urltoadd'];

... add Code to save $urltoadd in your database. 

If (file was added successfully){
echo 'successful';
}else {
echo 'failed';
}
? >
```

Answer (score 0):

On form submit you can bind a function and in that functiom
using jquery you can do `$('#result').text()`